# Calculating times between two datetime strings

Tags: python, datetime

I need to calculate times with `datetime`.

I have two strings `t1 = '12:00:00'` and `t2 = '13:00:00'`. I need to find the difference between them. I want to get it so that `total_time = t2 - t1` but, I can't just subtract them.

I already have `t1` and `t2` set in the format `'%H:%M:%S'`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: *"I can't just subtract them"* - why not?! Note that you will need to *convert the strings to `datetime` objects*, but you can find out how to do that in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You parse them into `datetime` objects and then subtract them

```
import datetime

t1 = '12:00:00'
t2 = '13:00:00'

print datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S")
# datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
```